# Ubuntu 16.04 install problem in VMware

Tags: 16.04, windows-10, vmware

I am unable to install Ubuntu 16.04 in VMware Workstation 14 Player. I am stuck at the location option, and it is not going forward.

[image]

Comment: please don't ask for help in questions. Try to provide more infos as edits to your queston: how is it stuck? can you show us a screenshot ? etc

Answer (score 1):

It clearly says that It needs 8.6 GB and You have only 5.4 GB. Create hard disk with at least recommended space.

Comment: Bro I have 132 GB free space